# bootstrap-datepicker- How to set automatically the date of the start day in end day?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I use `bootstrap-datepicker` in my app.

I have two input fields which I use it:

```
<div class="form-group number">
   <label for="addEventstart">Start date</label>
   <input type="text" class="signup-input required eventStartDate" id="addEventstart" name="startDate" placeholder="DD.MM.YYYY">
</div>

<div class="form-group number">
   <label for="addEventEnd">End date</label>
   <input type="text" class="signup-input eventEndDate" id="addEventEnd"
      name="endDate" placeholder="DD.MM.YYYY">
</div>
```

In case the fields of the `#addEventEnd` is empty I want to automatically put the chosen date of the `#addEventstart` input in it.

Comment: `if (condition) {$("#addEventEnd").val($("#addEventstart").val())}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below link may be help you

```
http://code.runnable.com/UmOmQbKV4wpoAAGa/bootstrap-datepicker-example-date-range-from-to-with-%22today%22-button-activated2
```

Comment: It updates both of the field. I have to update automatically just one of them on specific condition